# CSS attribute + pseudo-element with dynamic source strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select first-child with a specific attribute (aria-hidden="false")
and there is some strange behavior - looks like the attribute selector is getting kind of ignored - and it gets even stranger when the attribute changes dynamically (through javascript)

```
<ul>
  <li aria-hidden="true"><p class=""><a href=""><span>1</span></a></p></li>
  <li id="id" aria-hidden="false"><p class=""><a href=""><span>2</span></a></p></li>
  <li aria-hidden="false"><p class=""><a href=""><span>3</span></a></p></li>
  <li aria-hidden="false"><p class=""><a href=""><span>4</span></a></p></li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS:

```
ul li[aria-hidden=false]:nth-child(1) a {
  color: #00FF00;
  font-size: 30px;
}
ul li[aria-hidden=false]:nth-child(2) a {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-size: 30px;
}
ul li[aria-hidden=false]:first-child a {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

please see the filddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/11sd2r24/5/

do you know how can is select first "li" with aria-hidden attribute set to false

Comment: The `nth-child` pseudo element looks at the order of sibling elements in the DOM, and is not affected by the part of the selector that selects by attribute. Your selector `li[aria-hidden=false]:nth-child(1)` means, "An `<li>` element with attribute "aria-hidden" having the value "false", and which is the first child of its parent element".

Comment: pseudo-class* Attribute selectors and pseudo-*elements* have a separate category of bugs all on their own. The behavior that is seen here, on the other hand, is not a bug.

Answer (score 4):

The `:nth-child` selector counts all elements on the same level, **not** only matching ones.

The only way I know to select the nth matching element is `:nth-match`, but that<strike>'s</strike> was [part of a CSS4 draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo), but [removed afterwards](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#changes) and [`:nth-child` empowered](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#nth-child-pseudo).

**Update:**

For simple use cases, you achieve similar results by using the `+` combinator.

For instance, you can apply styles to exactly the second matching item by:

```
/* style each matching one after the first */
ul li[aria-hidden=false] + li[aria-hidden=false] a {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
/* revert for each one after the second */
ul li[aria-hidden=false] + li[aria-hidden=false] + li[aria-hidden=false] a {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

*[Your updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11sd2r24/10/)*

Comment: thanks, that would explain this behaviour, it's a pity that these attributes are not combined

Comment: You could try to use `+` for simple use cases; see my edit. But for complex scenarios, this could get messy...

Comment: "but that's hardly supported by browsers yet" ... and no longer even exists, as stated in my answer to that question.

Comment: @BoltClock Well, it is in the [CSS selectors level 4 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo), or am I missing something?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach, the CSS Selectors level 4 draft has been significantly changed since 2013, please see the latest [ED](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/). By the way, the new syntax (`:nth-child(An + B of ...)`) is already supported in newest WebKit browsers (e.g. Safari 9)